# Query JSONPath in JQ Format

Tags: bash, jq, jsonpath

I have JSONPath:

```
$.endpointAgents[?(@.clients.userName=~ 'a')].agentId
```

How it will look in `jq` format on Linux??

```sh
jq '.endpointAgents [] | select(.clients.userName=~"a") | {agentId}')"
```

does not work.

Code:

```json
{
  "endpointAgents": [
    {
      "agentId": "MyId",
      "agentName": "MYNAME",
      "location": {
        "locationName": "location"
      },
      "clients": [
        {
          "userProfile": {
            "userName": "Name"
          },
          "browserExtensions": [
            {
              "active": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "totalMemory": "16222 MB",
      "agentType": "enterprise"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: jq does not have a similar query structure like JSONPath. You need to share your input and post an expected output

Comment: added code to post

Comment: Please post the desired output

Comment: I want to get userName value by specifying agentId

Comment: Your jsonpath doesn't mesh with the JSON you provided

Comment: Don't ask to translate. If you do't understand the original, ask about that. If you don't know how to do something in the new language, ask that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get userName value by specifying agentId

```
jq '.endpointAgents[] | select(.agentId == "MyId") | .clients[].userProfile.userName'
```

Will output `"Name"`

---

- `.endpointAgents[]`
  Loop over each `endpointAgent`
- `select(.agentId == "MyId")`
  Select the objects where `.agentId == "MyId"`
- `.clients[].userProfile.userName`
  Since `clients` is an array, loop over it, and show `.userProfile.userName` for each object.

---

#### [Try it online!](https://jqplay.org/s/t0OoN_iCfC)

Comment: And if you get agentId by userName? How should the code be changed?

Comment: That's a whole different query. Since userNames exist in an array of objects, it's a bit more complicated then this answer. Consider asking this in a new question to avoid changing the topic here. Consider reading [ask] if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to produce the agent id of endpoints with a client whose name matches `a`.

```
.endpointAgents[] |
select( any( .clients[].userProfile.userName; test("a") ) ) |
.agentId
```

To produce the agent id of endpoints with a client whose name is equal to `a`, use the following instead:

```
.endpointAgents[] |
select( any( .clients[].userProfile.userName; . == "a" ) ) |
.agentId
```